# How to use a specific groovy version in a particular stage within a declarative pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

On my windows machine,

```
groovy -version
Groovy Version: 3.0.8 JVM: 16.0.1 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Windows 10
```

I have two groovy installations as well through **Global Tool Configuration** with names-

```
Groovy 3.0.5
Groovy 3.0.6
```

I intend to execute a groovy code within a declarative pipeline.

The Jenkins installation which I have, was shipped with `groovy-all-2.4.12` which doesn't ships with `groovy.xml.XmlSlurper`

The below is the piece of code

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    
    tools {
        nodejs 'NodeJS'
    }
    
    stages {
        stage('Hello') {
            steps {
                echo 'Hello World'
            }
        }
        
        stage('Initial-Checks') {
            steps {
                
                bat "npm -v"
                bat "groovy -v"  // gives the one installed on windows(i.e. 3.0.8)
        }}
        
        stage('Policy-Code Analysis') {
            steps {
                 script {
                    def text = '''
                        <list>
                            <technology>
                                <name>Jenkins, Groovy</name>
                            </technology>
                        </list>
                    '''

                    def list = new XmlSlurper().parseText(text) 

                    assert list instanceof groovy.xml.slurpersupport.GPathResult 
                    println list.technology.name
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Running this, results in

```
unable to resolve class groovy.xml.XmlSlurper 
   def list = new groovy.xml.XmlSlurper().parseText(text)
```

How can i use the `groovy version 3.0.6` for the code wrapped within `script { ... }` and not the version which Jenkins is using?

Also, the below doesn't works with tooling

```
pipeline {
        agent any

        stages {  
            stage ("first") {
                tools {
                   groovy "Groovy 3.0.5"
                }
                steps {
                    bat 'groovy -version'  // gives 3.0.8 and not 3.0.5
                }
            }
            stage("second"){
                tools {
                   groovy "Groovy 3.0.6"
                }
                steps{
                    bat 'groovy -version'  // gives 3.0.8 and not 3.0.6
                }
            }
       }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First options is to use different agents in separate stages, which has different groovy versions installed (docker images for example).

```
pipeline {
  agent none
  stages {
    stage {
      agent { label 'some_label' }
      steps {
        bat 'groovy -version'
      }
    stage("second"){
      agent { label 'another_label' }
      steps{
        bat 'groovy -version'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

There is a workaround to use groovy tool.

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  environment {
    GROOVY_HOME = tool name: '3.0.4', type: 'hudson.plugins.groovy.GroovyInstallation'
  }
  stages {
    stage ('run helloworld.groovy') {
      steps {
        sh '''
          echo 'println "Hello World!"' > helloworld.groovy
          ${GROOVY_HOME}/bin/groovy helloworld.groovy
        '''
      }
    }
  }
}
```